# File Upload in Joomla 3 Module

Tags: file, joomla, module, upload

I would like have file uploading in joomla 3 backend module.

I referred https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package but no file upload button appears. Perhaps I get something wrong or put it in wrong file?

Anyone can help? :D

Thank you.

Below codes in .xml between files and languages tags.

```
<params>
    <param name="dir" type="text" label="Directory" description="Directory Upload" default="upload"/>
    <param name="type" type="list" default="*" label="Select a file type" description="File type">
         <option value="*">Any File </option>
         <option value="image/png">PNG</option>
         <option value="image/gif">GIF</option>
         <option value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
         <option value="application/zip">ZIP</option>
         <option value="application/x-gzip">TAR.GZ</option>
         <option value="text/html">HTML</option>
         <option value="text/plain">TXT</option>
         <option value="application/pdf">PDF</option>
         <option value="application/msword">DOC</option>
       </param>          
    <param name="user_names" type="text" label="User Names (optional)" description="Names users (optionas)" default=""/>    
</params>
```

Below in mymodule.php after 'defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');' line.

```
//Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

$max = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
$module_dir = $params->get( 'dir' );
$file_type = $params->get( 'type' );

$user_names = $params->get( 'user_names' );
$msg = '';

function fileUpload($max, $module_dir, $file_type, $msg){
//Retrieve file details from uploaded file, sent from upload form
$file = JRequest::getVar('file_upload', null, 'files', 'array'); 
// Retorna: Array ( [name] => mod_simpleupload_1.2.1.zip [type] => application/zip 
// [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpo3VG9F [error] => 0 [size] => 4463 ) 

if(isset($file)){ 
    //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

    if($file['size'] > $max) $msg = JText::_('ONLY_FILES_UNDER').' '.$max;
    //Set up the source and destination of the file

    $src = $file['tmp_name'];
    $dest = $module_dir . DS . $filename;

    //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
    if ($file['type'] == $file_type || $file_type == '*') { 
       if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ) {

           //Redirect to a page of your choice
        $msg = JText::_('FILE_SAVE_AS').' '.$dest;
       } else {
          //Redirect and throw an error message
        $msg = JText::_('ERROR_IN_UPLOAD');
       }
    } else {
       //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
        $msg = JText::_('FILE_TYPE_INVALID');
    }

    $msg = "<script>alert('". $msg ."');</script>";
}
return $msg;
}

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$username = $user->get('username');

$acc = 0;
$session =& JFactory::getSession(); 

if(isset($user_names)) {
$more = strpos($user_names, ',',0);
if($more >0){
    $user_names = explode(',',$user_names);
    foreach($user_names as $un){
        if($un == $username) {
            $session->set($acc, 1); 
        }else{
            $session->set($acc, 0); 
        }
    }
}else{
    if ($user_names == $username) $session->set($acc, 1); 
}
}else{
if(isset($username)) $session->set($acc, 1); 
}

if($session->get($acc) == 1){
?>

<form name="imgform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"     onSubmit="if(file_upload.value=='') {alert('Choose a file!');return false;}">
<?php echo JText::_('CHOOSE_FILE'); ?> <input type="file" name="file_upload" size="10" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<?php
print fileUpload($max, $module_dir, $file_type, $msg);
}

// Adapted from http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package
?>
```

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: @Lodder there you go! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok 2 things that are wrong.

Firstly, you're using `<params>` which is the old method for parameter fields. You need to use fields as show in the documentation below:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_Form_Fields

Secondly, your `mymodule.php` file is for the frontend of the module and will not work with anything to do with the backend apart from grabbing data such as your parameters.

What you can do is either use the [media](https://docs.joomla.org/Media_form_field_type) type field of create a [custom form field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type).

Hope this helps